# How to dynamically create nested array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want create a nested array from a config file dynamically. 
My config file structure is like this:

```
parameter1 value1;
parameter2 value2;
parameter3 value3;

block1{
    parameter1-1 value1-1;
    parameter1-2 value1-2;

    block1-1{
        parameter1-1-1 value1-1-1;
        parameter1-1-2 value1-1-2;

        block1-1-1{
            parameter1-1-1-1 value1-1-1-1;
            parameter1-1-1-2 value1-1-1-2;
        }
        block1-1-2{
            parameter1-1-2-1 value1-1-2-1;
            parameter1-1-2-2 value1-1-2-2;
        }
    }
    block1-2{
        parameter1-2-1 value1-2-1;
        parameter1-2-2 value1-2-2;

        block1-2-1{
            parameter1-2-1-1 value1-2-1-1;
            parameter1-2-1-2 value1-2-1-2;
        }
        block1-2-2{
            parameter1-2-2-1 value1-2-2-1;
            parameter1-2-2-2 value1-2-2-2;
        }
    }
}

block2{
    parameter2-1 value2-1;
    parameter2-2 value2-2;

    block2-1{
        parameter2-1-1 value2-1-1;
        parameter2-1-2 value2-1-2;

        block2-1-1{
            parameter2-1-1-1 value2-1-1-1;
            parameter2-1-1-2 value2-1-1-2;
        }
        block2-1-2{
            parameter2-1-2-1 value2-1-2-1;
            parameter2-1-2-2 value2-1-2-2;
        }
    }
    block2-2{
    parameter2-2-1 value2-2-1;
    parameter2-2-2 value2-2-2;

    block2-2-1{
        parameter2-2-1-1 value2-2-1-1;
        parameter2-2-1-2 value2-2-1-2;
    }
    block2-2-2{
        parameter2-2-2-1 value2-2-2-1;
        parameter2-2-2-2 value2-2-2-2;
        }
    }
}
```

and i want this array dynamically in php:

```
$blocks = array(
    $parameter => $value,
    $parameter => $value,
    $block => array(
        $parameter => $value,
        $parameter => $value,
        $block => array(
            $parameter => $value,
            $parameter => $value,
            $block => array(
                $parameter => $value,
                $parameter => $value
                ...
           )
        )
    )
);
```

How to create dynamically nested array in PHP

### Thanks.

UPDATE:

- I read file line by line to an array and i want create above structure for edit it and write it again to config file.
- I means from "dynamic" is creating array inside "for" or other similar things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this... (change "conf.txt" to "your conf file name")

```
<?php
$file = fopen("conf.txt","r");
$array = array();
$a = createArray($file, $array);
fclose($file);

print("<pre>".print_r($a,true)."</pre>");

function createArray($file, $array){
  while(! feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
    $line = trim($line);
    if ($line == ""){
        continue;
    }
    if (strpos($line,'{') !== false){
        $line = trim(str_replace('{','',$line));
        $array[$line] = array();
        $array[$line]  = createArray($file, $array[$line]);
    } else if (strpos($line,'}') !== false) {
        return $array;
    } else {
        $line = str_replace(';','',$line);
        $key  = strtok($line, ' ');
        $value = strtok(' ');
        $array[$key] = $value;
    }
  }
  return $array;
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you give me some reference for learning recursive functions? thank you.

Comment: you are Well come :).. Read chapter 4 (Divide-and-Conquer) of the book "Introduction to Algorithms". I found it online to download but I'm not sure if it's legal (http://ldc.usb.ve/~xiomara/ci2525/ALG_3rd.pdf). Also you may google about "Divide and conquer" and "recursive functions".

Answer (score 0):

Creating array dynamically:

in all PHP versions:

```
$foo = array();
```

in PHP 5.4+ (aka "short syntax"):

```
$foo = [];
```

Creating nested array dynamically:

```
$foo = [];
$foo['bar'] = [];
$foo['bar']['zoo'] = [];
```

or

```
$foo = [];
$bar = ['zoo' => []];
$foo['bar'] = $bar;
```

And finally call

```
print_r($foo);
```

to see what you got created. Both cases are equal so you will see:

```
Array
(
    [bar] => Array
        (
            [zoo] => Array
                (
                )
        )
}
```

Please see docs on array: http://php.net/manua/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: thank you. Is this dynamic?
i want it inside "foreach" or similar things.

Comment: Dynamic means during code execution. It does not matter when you add element to your array in `foreach`, `for`, `do` or just as in my examples. At the end you got `array` with childs added to it dynamically, depending on your code execution

Comment: how to yo can create nested arrays inside "for"? i want nest it up to 100 time!

Comment: It depends on what nesting you need? 100 elements nest into each other (what's the point?). Anyway, you can always add new item to array like that: `$a['foo']['bar']['zzz']['ttt'] = array('here');` to get deep nesting.

Comment: Thank for your answer, i don't follow specific point. only i want know is it possible?! or must be nest array one by one in my code? any way i thank you for your time. :D

Comment: Nested array means array that contains other arrays as its children. In PHP you are not limited to how you add items to your array, so yes, it's perfectly possible and it's quite common to build arrays from code (usually `foreach` or `for`).

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski i am also stuck with same issue. May be you can help me with this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64076032/php-create-nested-array-for-data