# Create Nested Array for data

Tags: php

I am running some SQL query to get the data and then I am adding them into an array.
I am trying to achieve the data in nested array. As school table is returning multiple data for users table.

Here is the code.

```
$res=array();

$data = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name, rollno, pic from `users` as a and a.uid = ?"); 
$data ->bind_param("i", $uid);
$data->execute();
$data->store_result();
$data->bind_result($name, $rollno, $pic);
                        
if($data->num_rows != 0){
    while ($data->fetch()){
            $name = $name;
            $rollno = $rollno;
            $pic = $pic;    
            
        $res['content'][] = array(
                    "name" => $name,
                    "rollno" => $rollno,
                    "pic" => $pic
        );      
    

$sdata = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT a.uid, a.class, a.subject, a.board from `school` as a and a.uid = ?"); 
$sdata ->bind_param("i", $uid);
$sdata->execute();
$sdata->store_result();
$sdata->bind_result( $uid, $class, $subject, $board);
                        
        if($sdata->num_rows != 0){
            while ($sdata->fetch()){
                    $uid = $uid;
                    $class = $class;
                    $subject = $subject;
                    $board = $board;    
                    
                $res['content']['pricing'][] = array(
                            "uid" => $uid,
                            "class" => $class,
                            "subject" => $subject,
                            "board" => $board
                );      
            }
            }
        }
    }
```

Above method is giving me output like this.

```
Array
(
    [content] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Test User1
                    [rollno] => 9
                    [pic] => 9_1599452969.jpg
                   
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Test User2
                    [rollno] => 8
                    [pic] => 8_1599452969.jpg
                    
                )

            [pricing] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [uid] => 8
                            [class] => 2
                            [subject] => Math
                            [board] => CBSE
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [uid] => 8
                            [class] => 2
                            [subject] => Science
                            [board] => CBSE
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [uid] => 9
                            [class] => 2
                            [subject] => Science
                            [board] => CBSE
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [uid] =>9
                            [class] => 2
                            [subject] => English
                            [board] => CBSE
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [uid] => 9
                            [class] => 2
                            [subject] => Math
                            [board] => CBSE
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

As you can see pricing array data is coming after Content data.
I want it to be in same line in nested way.

```
  Array
(
    [content] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Test User1
                    [rollno] => 9
                    [pic] => 9_1599452969.jpg
                    [Pricing][0] => Array
                        (
                            [uid] => 9
                            [class] => 2
                            [subject] => Science
                            [board] => CBSE
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [uid] =>9
                            [class] => 2
                            [subject] => English
                            [board] => CBSE
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [uid] => 9
                            [class] => 2
                            [subject] => Math
                            [board] => CBSE
                        ) 
                   
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Test User2
                    [rollno] => 8
                    [pic] => 8_1599452969.jpg
                    [pricing][0] => Array
                        (
                            [uid] => 8
                            [class] => 2
                            [subject] => Math
                            [board] => CBSE
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [uid] => 8
                            [class] => 2
                            [subject] => Science
                            [board] => CBSE
                        )
                )

            [pricing] => Array
                (
                    

                    

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to create temporary array, feed it with all data and then add to `$res`. So instead of

```
        $res['content'][] = array(
                    "name" => $name,
                    "rollno" => $rollno,
                    "pic" => $pic
        );
```

do

```
        $tmp = array(
                    "name" => $name,
                    "rollno" => $rollno,
                    "pic" => $pic
        );
```

Then add pricing to it - instead of

```
                $res['content']['pricing'][] = array(
                            "uid" => $uid,
                            "class" => $class,
                            "subject" => $subject,
                            "board" => $board
                );
```

add to temporary array

```
                $tmp['pricing'][] = array(
                            "uid" => $uid,
                            "class" => $class,
                            "subject" => $subject,
                            "board" => $board
                );
```

And finally, before doing another iteration of main loop add it to `$res`

```
$res['content'][] = $tmp;
```